# Created my own version of Binary Search, can't understand why it is faster than the regular approach?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, time-complexity, binary-search

Hello to everyone who reads this post. I recently graduated and I'm basically going over every concept I ever learned to refresh my memory or sharpen my skills even better so that I may apply to companies and get hired. My first refresher is going over binary search and I decided to write my own version without looking over the regular approach. I happen to write the following code in which I compared the time complexity of the regular approach to my own version of binary search. **Although, my binary search seems to integrate both linear search and binary search and yet it seems it is somehow faster than the regular approach and I just don't understand why. Linear search is utilized for when the key is greater than the middle element, which seems like it would actually increase the time complexity of the search. You can see this within my code of the last else if condition in *"myBinarySearch"* method.** Yet, even after searching through 15,000 integers of an array, my version is still faster.

Can anyone please explain to me why my version is much faster? Below is the regular approach compared to my version of binary search. My version is only slower when searching for a key that does not exist and is over excessive, for example, searching for 16,000. It must be excessive, because searching for 15,001 does result in a faster time of returning -1.

I've concluded that it is because I only used one variable as oppose to using 3 variables in the regular approach which is checking and/or updating these variables when looping through the array. Although, the linear search in the last else if statement in my method throws me off and makes me wonder how this does not increase the time complexity.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[15000];
    File file; 
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
       file = new File("../Java/bin/IntroToJavaBook/largeArray.txt");
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       String st;
       int i = 0;
       while((st = br.readLine()) != null) 
       {
           array[i] = Integer.parseInt(st);
           i++;
       }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    int key = 4200;
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(binarySearch(array, key));
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println(duration);

    long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(myBinarySearch(array, key));
    long endTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    long duration1 = (endTime1 - startTime1);
    System.out.println(duration1);

}

static int binarySearch(int[] array, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = array.length - 1;
    while (high >= low) 
    {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2; 
        if (key < array[mid])
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (key == array[mid])
        {
            return mid; 
        }
        else
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

static int myBinarySearch(int[] array, int key) {
    int half = array.length/2;
    while(true)
    {
        if(half == 0 || half == array.length)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(key < array[half])
        {
            half /= 2;
        }
        else if(key == array[half])
        {
            return half;
        }
        else if(key > array[half])
        {
            half = half + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't tell much without seeing the code for binarySearch and myBinarySearch

Comment: Mirco benchmarks are hard to do right, especially with JVM. You said you compared the time complexity and then started talking about conditions where each one is faster. Go back and review the time complexity topic again, benchmarking has nothing to do with it. You should get a simple mathematical equations `O()` in terms on `n`. The traditional bin search is O(log2(n)) sounds like yours may be O(log2(n) + n/2) which you can see from easy algebra is slower. Benchmarks generally measure best/worst/small n cases and do not tell you much about the algorithm as a whole.

Comment: It can't be faster, of course. The usual way of writing your code would be `half += half/2` and `half -= half/2` depending on the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You confuse complexity with speed. 
In complexity, n>1000, even if you run a test with n=500.